# Deserializar respuesta servicio soap en c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialización

Actualmente recibo esta respuesta de un servicio svc soap:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>[0417] - El identificador de petición y de solicitud no coinciden.</faultstring>
         <faultactor>Seguridad Social</faultactor>
         <detail>
            <Atributos xmlns="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/soapfaultatributos">
               <IdPeticion>HACSGTIC-2016111056-0036</IdPeticion>
               <NumElementos>1</NumElementos>
               <TimeStamp>2016-11-10T11:56:51.687+01.00</TimeStamp>
               <Estado>
                  <CodigoEstado>0417</CodigoEstado>
                  <LiteralError>[0417] - El identificador de petición y de solicitud no coinciden.</LiteralError>
                  <TiempoEstimadoRespuesta />
               </Estado>
               <CodigoCertificado>Q2827002CINSS001</CodigoCertificado>
            </Atributos>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Lo que necesito es deserializar el xml Atributos ya que tengo un objeto "Atributos" con las propiedades correspondientes al xml, a continuación os pongo la clase Atributos de la referencia del servicio:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/peticion")]
public partial class Atributos : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string idPeticionField;

    private int numElementosField;

    private string timeStampField;

    private Estado estadoField;

    private CodigoCertificado codigoCertificadoField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string IdPeticion {
        get {
            return this.idPeticionField;
        }
        set {
            this.idPeticionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IdPeticion");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public int NumElementos {
        get {
            return this.numElementosField;
        }
        set {
            this.numElementosField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("NumElementos");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string TimeStamp {
        get {
            return this.timeStampField;
        }
        set {
            this.timeStampField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeStamp");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public Estado Estado {
        get {
            return this.estadoField;
        }
        set {
            this.estadoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Estado");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public CodigoCertificado CodigoCertificado {
        get {
            return this.codigoCertificadoField;
        }
        set {
            this.codigoCertificadoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CodigoCertificado");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/peticion")]
public partial class Estado : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string codigoEstadoField;

    private string codigoEstadoSecundarioField;

    private string literalErrorField;

    private int tiempoEstimadoRespuestaField;

    private bool tiempoEstimadoRespuestaFieldSpecified;

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string CodigoEstado {
        get {
            return this.codigoEstadoField;
        }
        set {
            this.codigoEstadoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CodigoEstado");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string CodigoEstadoSecundario {
        get {
            return this.codigoEstadoSecundarioField;
        }
        set {
            this.codigoEstadoSecundarioField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CodigoEstadoSecundario");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string LiteralError {
        get {
            return this.literalErrorField;
        }
        set {
            this.literalErrorField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("LiteralError");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public int TiempoEstimadoRespuesta {
        get {
            return this.tiempoEstimadoRespuestaField;
        }
        set {
            this.tiempoEstimadoRespuestaField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TiempoEstimadoRespuesta");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TiempoEstimadoRespuestaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.tiempoEstimadoRespuestaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.tiempoEstimadoRespuestaFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TiempoEstimadoRespuestaSpecified");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/peticion")]
public enum CodigoCertificado {

    /// <comentarios/>
    Q2827002CINSS001,
}
```

*****Este es mi código que deserializa el xml al objeto "Atributos":

```
    public static T Deserializar<T>(string respuesta, string nameSpace, string xpath = "//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/p:Respuesta")
    {


        T objetoDeserializado = default(T);
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(respuesta);

        Dictionary<string, string> nsAdicionales = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        nsAdicionales.Add("s", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
        nsAdicionales.Add("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        nsAdicionales.Add("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        nsAdicionales.Add("p", nameSpace);
        XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        foreach (string prefijo in nsAdicionales.Keys)
        {
            nsm.AddNamespace(prefijo, nsAdicionales[prefijo]);
        }
        XmlNode nodoObjeto = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath, nsm);
        if (nodoObjeto != null)
        {

            try
            {
                //Se añade el atributo XmlRootAttribute para aquellos casos que esté definido el objeto
                //con un nombre y se utilice con otro.
                XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                xRoot.ElementName = nodoObjeto.Name;
                xRoot.Namespace = nodoObjeto.NamespaceURI;
                var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T), xRoot);
                XmlReader xmlReader = nodoObjeto.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree();
                var obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                objetoDeserializado = ((T)obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                respuesta = "Error al intentar deserializar el objeto soap: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return objetoDeserializado;
    }
```

Donde T es del tipo "SCSP.ServiciosCompartidos.INSS.ConsultaPrestaciones.Atributos" pues bien, no da error, pero si vemos el objeto Deserializado, me pone todos los valores como NULL

Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que los namespaces no corresponden entre el XML y las clases que usas para deserialización.

En tus clases, todos definen el namespace como http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/peticion:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/peticion")]
```

Pero el nodo `Atributos` en tu XML define un namespace diferente, http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/soapfaultatributos:

```
<Atributos xmlns="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/soapfaultatributos">
```

Tendrás que averiguar por qué existe esta diferencia, pero el punto es que si corriges el namespace en tu XML, verás que ahora sí va a intentar deserializar los valores en las clases y sus propiedades respectivas.

**Nota adicional**

Problema aparte, te advierto que tal vez tengas problema con:

```
<TiempoEstimadoRespuesta />
```

...ya que no creo que pueda deserializar un nodo vacío a un campo de tipo `int`. Te aviso por si recibes un error después de corregir el problema principal.

Comment: Hola sstan. Perdonad, copié mal el objeto con el cual deserializo la respuesta, el que uso es el mismo que el que os puse pero con el namespace="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/soapfaultatributos")]

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda, he podido ver que si pongo esta línea de codigo en el trozo donde deserializo "  xRoot.IsNullable = true;     ", el xml se deserializa correctamente cuando el nodo TiempoEstimadoRespuesta me viene con valor 0 "<TiempoEstimadoRespuesta >0<TiempoEstimadoRespuesta />" en cambio cuando el nodo me viene del servicio de esta manera "<TiempoEstimadoRespuesta />" es decir vacío, el resultado del objeto en la deserialización es un null. ¿Me podríais ayudar?

Comment: Acabo de resolver el segundo problema, y es eliminando las etiquetas que me vienen sin valor en el xml de esta manera:    
    XmlNodeList emptyElements = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(@"//*[not(node())]");
    for (int i = emptyElements.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    emptyElements[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(emptyElements[i]);
    }